# find the intersection of 4 files

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal, string-search

How do you find intersection of 4 files?

I used `grep -Fx -f 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt`, but it seems that it only works for 2 files. Similarly `comm -12 1.txt 2.txt` can't be expanded to 4 files and requires data to be sorted. My data isn't sorted, in fact, it shouldn't be. I am on Mac.

Input:

```
1.txt
.css
.haha
.hehe
2.txt
.ajkad
.shdja
.hehe

3.txt
.css1
.aaaaa
.hehe

4.txt
.qwqw
.kkkmsm
.hehe
```

Output: `.hehe`

I used grep first on 1 and 2 stored in 12.txt, than on 3 and 4,stored in 34.txt then used grep again on 12.txt and 34.txt. But there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by intersection in this case? Can you provide a short input example and desired output?

Comment: there you go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the greps:

```
grep -f 1.txt 2.txt \
| grep -f- 3.txt \
| grep -f- 4.txt
```

The `-f-` means the input coming from the pipe is used, not a real file.

Comment: @sanjihan: What about  `grep -f <(grep -f <(grep -f 1.txt 2.txt) 3.txt) 4.txt` ?

Comment: It is correct, i misinterpreted my data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the intersection between two:

```
$ grep -Fx -f f1.txt f2.txt
.hehe
```

Then use that as input with the other two:

```
$ grep -f <(grep -Fx -f f1.txt f2.txt) f3.txt f4.txt
f3.txt:.hehe
f4.txt:.hehe
```

Or, if you just want a single word:

```
$ grep -f <( grep -f <(grep -Fx -f f1.txt f2.txt) f3.txt) f4.txt
.hehe
```